# BSON::Binary::InvalidType "my file content" is not a valid binary type. Please use one of :generic, :function, :old, :uuid_old, :uuid, :md5, :user.):

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, gridfs, bson, mongoid3

I am trying to save files into gridfs using carrierwave mongoid in rails. I am unable to do this process due to this error:

```
BSON::Binary::InvalidType ("my file content" is not a valid binary type. 
Please use one of :generic, :function, :old, :uuid_old, :uuid, :md5, :user.):
```

Can anyone please help me out of this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this question was revived with a bounty but does not include an example that leads to failure.  Please also post what you have tried on your own. For more details, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve